# How to set connect-timeout value of curl more than 120 sec in linux systems?

Tags: curl

Tried curl with connect-timeout value more than 120 sec but it is not waiting for specified time. It stops trying to connect after 120 sec eventhough inputted connect-timeout is 180 sec(more than 120 sec). I am using Linux machine.
How to set connect-timeout value more than 120 sec in linux?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:
`curl --connect-timeout 180 --max-time 180 https://www.example.com`, but....

`120 seconds` is the limit on many providers like `Cloudflare`. If you're trying to curl a website, and you're going over 120 seconds, likely the server you're trying to connect to is dropping you. (Or the server's firewall is dropping you, or his loadbalancer, etc.)